# firebase add child to non-exist parent

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my case, the data structure is:

```
root -> A -> B -> C
```

Sometimes when I try to add data to C, A and B still not being created, if I try to add B with below code, crash happen:

```
dbref.child("A").child("B").child("C").setValue("hello");
```

Maybe I need to create A and B firstly but since everything is async, how can I create all childs in one function call?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's working,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setData();
    }

    public void setData()
    {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("A").child("B").child("C");

        myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

[image]

Hope It's helpful for you.